# ordinary generating function of some sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series

What is the ordinary generating function of the sequence whose general term is $a_n = {n+k \choose k}$?. I cannot find it in the list given in the book generatingfunctionology, by Herbert S. Wilf. Is there a more comprehensive list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$. Recall that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$,and this is 2.5.7 on page 53 of generatingfunctionology.

Comment: Of course, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=\binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{n+k}{n}$,   aslo  $$(1+x)^{k+n}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^i$$,  so generating function of the sequence is $(1+x)^{k+n}$

Comment: Well, not exactly. Your left hand side is a polynomial in $x$, while your right hand side is an infinite series. But the property of the binomial coefficients is useful anyway; thanks.

Comment: :):):):):):):):)